# Maximum update depth exceeded when in map function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass a function from a parent to a child so when someone clicks on the child component it will toggle with a different one. So what i have done is

```
class Comp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {active: true};

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
  if(this.state.active)
              {this.state.callerData.map((agent, i) => (
                <CompAltWidget compalt={compalt} key={i} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
              ))}
              else if(!this.state.active){this.state.callerData.map((agent, i) => (
                <compWidget comp={comp} key={i} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
              ))}
</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Comp;
```

And the child components:

```
class CompWidget extends Component {
  handleClick() {
    this.props.handleClick();
  }
render() {
    return (
      <div >
<div className="wrapper" onClick={this.props.handleClick()}>
                      <LineChart line1Data={this.props.comp} />
            </div>
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ComptWidget;
```

and the second component where CompWidget -> CompAltWidget. 
The message i get is `Maximum update depth exceeded`, but even when I followed the following solution [ReactJS: Maximum update depth exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error) and changed the `<CompAltWidget compalt={compalt} key={i} handleClick={this.handleClick()} />` to `<CompAltWidget compalt={compalt} key={i} handleClick={this.handleClick} />` the error still occurs. Can anyone help with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write

```
<div className="wrapper" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
```