# Redirect component causing 'Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Can someone please shed some light as to why my code is returning `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded.`

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect from="/" to="/issues" />
        <Route exact path="/issues" component={IssueList} />
        <Route exact path="/issues/:id" component={IssueEdit} />
        <Route path="*" component={IssueNotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

But when I move the `<Redirect from="/" to="/issues" />` component down in  route list, the error goes away but the functionality is not the one desired. I do have a `setState` in the `IssueList` component under the `componentDidMount` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS: Maximum update depth exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error)

Comment: So does that mean that `BrowserRouter` triggers a `render()` and then the `Redirect` triggers another `render()` which then continues on an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

you need match from exactly `<Redirect exact from="/" to="/issues" />`

if not, setting `from="/"` will match each route path and take it redirect infinitely.

Comment: The `exact` parameter is understood. My question was more for addressing which component is triggering an infinite loop that React prevents from executing.