# Trying to update the state using setstate inside the return in react component and getting "Maximum update depth exceeded error"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to update the state directly inside the return without using any of the life cycle method and am getting error like this:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error) for the above error, but I didn't get an appropriate solution. Is it always necessary to use a function or life cycle method to update the state?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "john"
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          {this.state.name}
          {this.setState({ name: "abc" })}
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I wrote the above code and am getting the error but in console the state value is getting update and printing it in many times.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have this error because `setState` triggers re-render of the component each time when your component renders. This causes an endless loop of updates.

   > setState() will always lead to a re-render unless shouldComponentUpdate() returns false.
2. Yes, it is necessary to use a function or life cycle method to update the state. You must not update a state directly in a render function. You should prepare your data for rendering before render and you should update a state in lifecycle methods or in callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `setState` inside the `render` method. You cannot use `setState` inside the `render` method because it will cause the Component to re-render again and again. Because in react application a Component get re-rendered only if Props pass to that component or when `setState` is called.

> So you can use `componentDidMount` life-cycle to set the state.