# Maximum update depth exceeded. React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to pass values from one component to another. This is my parent component.

```
<View>
   { this.state.errors ? <ErrorNotice content={this.state.content} /> : null}
</View>
```

And this is my child component

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            errorMessage : "",
            visibility: false
        }
    }

    closeErrorNotice = ()=>{
        this.setState({
            visibility : false
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.errorContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.errorText}>
                    {this.props.content.errorMessage}
                </Text>
                <Icon
                    name="x"
                    color="#454749"
                    size={25}
                    style={styles.closeButton}
                    onPress= {this.closeErrorNotice()}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

But I am getting Maximum update depth exceeded. 
I can't find the error. Can anyone find the error.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48497410/10932034 for same issue

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the function when passing to `onPress`. You're getting an infinite loop because you're calling the function that updates the state which makes the function get called again. You need to pass the function definition, not the result of calling the function.

`onPress= {this.closeErrorNotice}`