# Cannot do calculations with values passed as props in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm developing a React Native app. There, I'm using `react-native-simple-gauge` and I want to fill the gauge by calculating the percentage value.

I'm passing the value (`value`) and the reference value (`refValue`) as props to the particular component. Then, I calculated the percentage as follows.

`this.props.value / this.props.refValue * 100`

But, this gives me an error saying that

`Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWilUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

BTW, I'm not using any of `setState, componentWillUpdate, componentDidUpdate` in my component.

The relevant code segment is given below.

```
<AnimatedGaugeProgress
    size={50}
    width={3}
    fill={this.props.value / this.props.refValue * 100}
    rotation={90}
    cropDegree={90}
    tintColor={this.props.tintColor}
    backgroundColor="#808080"
 />
```

When I hard code and replace `this.props.refValue`, it works well.

```
<AnimatedGaugeProgress
   size={50}
   width={3}
   fill={this.props.value / 20 * 100}
   rotation={90}
   cropDegree={90}
   tintColor={this.props.tintColor}
   backgroundColor="#808080"
 />
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Are you perhaps frequently calling something that is updating `this.props.refValue` constantly (thus triggering many re-renders)? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48497410/7548163, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by,

1. First, calculate what is needed and set the result to a state.
2. Then, pass the resulting state as props to component.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you have provided, the only difference is the `this.props.refValue`.

If that prop is constantly changing, it will cause the `AnimatedGaugeProgress` component to re-render each time.

The easiest way to find the issue is to find out the place where you are changing the value of `refValue`. Check in the lifecycle methods, specially ones which can trigger a render.