# Error: " ` Maximum update depth exceed` "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need help here.

I've already found a similar question here in StackOverflow ([Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error/59795423?noredirect=1#comment105732976_59795423))

I've read and try to figure out what could be wrong with my code. I'm a little bit new as a developer and I'm still learning how to debug a code, so please sorry if the answer is pop uping in my face but I really need a clarity here.

I'm developing a project in React-Redux, and when I try to load the App it shows the error of the title.

I suspect that the error is in my App.js. There go below part of the code:

```
class App extends Component {  

  resetActiveIndexToZero = () => {
    this.setState({ activeIndex: 0 })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { handleInitialData } = this.props
    handleInitialData()
  }

  render() {
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props    

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Fragment>
            <LoadingBar style={{ zIndex: 1000 }} />            
            {isAuthenticated && <Menu />}
            <div className='ui main text container' style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={RequiresAuth(QuestionList)} />
                <Route path='/add' component={QuestionNew} />
                <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route path='/questions/:question_id' component={RequiresAuth(QuestionView)} />
                <Route path='/leaderboard' component={RequiresAuth(Leaderboard)} />                                                     
                <Route path='/logout' component={Logout} />                   
                <Route path='/404' component={PageNotFound} />                          
              </Switch>
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>         
    )
  }  
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { authedUser } = state
    return { isAuthenticated: authedUser !== null }
}
```

I've tried some things, without success.

What could be wrong with this code?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the code of the archive RequiresAuth.js, as commented in an answer below:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
    class RequiresAuth extends React.Component {
        static propTypes = {
            isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool            
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.isAuthenticated ? <ComposedComponent {...this.props} /> 
                    : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { referrer: window.location.pathname}}} />}                   
                </div>
            )
        }    
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            isAuthenticated: state.authedUser !== null
        }
    }    

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(RequiresAuth)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the codesandbox: https://sit9d.csb.app/login

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but if `RequiresAuth` is an HoC, you [shouldn't be using it in the render method](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method).

Comment: Also why the arrow function? Why not a regular method? Why are you wrapping your routes in a fragment? There's a lot of weird stuff here. Please create a *minimal* reproduction case.

Comment: @Emile Bergeron, I've put the code of RequiresAuth.js above.

Comment: @Jared Smith, sorry man, I'm new in this development stuff, I know my code is not the clearest, but I intent to improve myself. I'll try to reproduce in codesandbox and put the link here for you.

Comment: Ok, so you're `RequiresAuth` is clearly a Higher-Order Component, so you should define the component with the HoC instead of wrapping it at runtime in the render function.

Comment: @jose-renato-m oh, don't worry too much about it. Someday you'll be experienced at Javascript and then you'll pick up another language and get to do it all over again. And again with the 3rd language. My python/clojure/typescript game is tight but my shell scripts are about 50% voodoo.

Comment: @Jared Smith.....LoL.......wait some minutes, I'm building the app in codesandbox.

Comment: @JaredSmith, I've done the codesandbox, the link is above.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, could you be clearer? I haven't understood, how do I define the component with the HOC?

Comment: In the file that you define the component, you could do, e.g. `export default RequiresAuth(QuestionList);`. This will export a new component instead a creating a new one each render-cycle.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, you say instead I export the function which wraps the class, I export direct the class? Is this what are you suggesting?

Comment: @EmileBergeron and Jared Smith, this issue I've found, and it was a weird thing. Just a wrong word I've put in the end of the component's code Login.js, instead of setAuthedUser I'd put as one of the arguments of mapStateToProps, it was authedUser and into return I'd put the same. So the app has worked, but still with some issues yet.

I've opened another question here in stackoverflow, could you kindly help me in this new issue?...here is the link of my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815541/how-to-persist-with-data-in-a-menu-grid-in-react-redux-application . Regards.

Comment: @JaredSmith, please see my comment above. Thanks.