# Maximum update depth exceeded with apollo hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

The following code throws the error "Maximum update depth exceeded" after clicking on the Toggle button.

It works after removing `allJobs` from the dependency array but I would like to understand why this error occurred and how to write it better.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-sky-3spv4)

```js
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

const JOBS = gql`
  query Jobs($cursor: String) {
    allJobs(first: 5, after: $cursor) {
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      edges {
        node {
          id
          jobTitle
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Countries = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const [, setJobs] = React.useState([]);
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(JOBS, {
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network"
  });
  const allJobs = data ? data.allJobs.edges.map(edge => edge.node) : undefined;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (visible) {
      setJobs(allJobs);
    }
  }, [visible, allJobs]);

  const toggleVisible = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggleVisible}>Toggle</button>
      {visible &&
        allJobs.map(job => (
          <div key={job.id}>
            <p>{job.jobTitle}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Every single render, your `allJobs` variable is reassigned, either to your mapped nodes or to `undefined`. Since it's also a dependency of your effect, and your effect itself will cause a rerender (if `visible` is true), this forces the effect to fire recursively.

Comment: You could probably wrap `allJobs` with `useMemo` to prevent recreating this array on every render.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error - This answer can help with `Maximum update depth exceeded`

Comment: @bsekula not applicable here. It's ok to pass a function reference to an onClick handler.

Comment: @tobiasfried Thanks, it works with `useMemo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better visibility:

Every single render, your allJobs variable is reassigned, either to your mapped nodes or to undefined. Since it's also a dependency of your effect, and your effect itself will cause a rerender (if visible is true), this forces the effect to fire recursively.

You can memoize `allJobs` to prevent recreating it on every render.

```
const allJobs = React.useMemo(() => {
  return data ? data.allJobs.edges.map(edge => edge.node) : undefined;
}, [data]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-flower-cbdwq)