# How to fix: 'Error: Maximum update depth exceeded'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new in React. Have problem with react-router

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Index.tsx

```
          <PrivateRoute path='/' component={Main} /> //without exact
          <Route path='/signin' component={SignIn} />
```

PrivateRoute.tsx:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      localStorage.getItem('authToken') ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{ pathname: '/signin', state: { from: props.location } }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
)
```

Main.tsx:

```
const Main: FC = () => {
  return (
    <App>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map(route => (
          <Route
            key={route.path}
            path={route.path}
            exact={route.exact}
            component={route.component}
          />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </App>
  )
}
```

routes.tsx:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/shop',
    key: 'market',
    component: props => (
      <LazyLoad
        component={React.lazy(() => import('./modules/shop/pages/Shop'))}
        {...props}
      />
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: () => <div>main</div>,
    skip: true,
  },
]
```

App.tsx:

```
const App: FC<AppProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const sidebarToggle = useState(false) // recommended: collapsed, setCollapsed
  return (
    <div className={classes.wrapper}>
      <SidebarContext.Provider value={sidebarToggle}>
        <Sidebar />
        <main className={classes.main}>
          <section className={classes.routeWrapper}>
            <Nav />
            <div className={classes.route}>{children}</div>
          </section>
        </main>
      </SidebarContext.Provider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

So, problem is: without exact route i don't have this error, but when pass exact props to PrivateRoute, my shop component not works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS: Maximum update depth exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error)

Comment: Hope this will help you

Comment: What happen when you remove `state: { from: props.location }` from `<Redirect ..` and pass location to `<SignIn ..` (if Signin needs location at all?) by using `useLocation` hook?

Comment: Ahh, you actually want to know from where user has been redirected

Comment: @iamwebkalakaar unfortunately no

Comment: ok let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Basically, `exact` prop will get rid of nesting ability of `Route`.

For example, your `Main` path is  `'/'`, so if you pass the `exact` prop like this:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Main} />
```

Then you can't have a nested route inside `Main` like `/shop`, although your shop component is nested inside `Main`.

2. As for the infinite loop error, it's usually because we mutate the component props or states inside the life circle methods (for example: `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` for class-based component, `useEffect` hook for functional component)

Please make sure **there is no where** you mutate the props or states **directly (without condition)** inside the life circle of component. For example, using `setState` directly inside `componentDidUpdate` will cause an infinite loop.