# Inline hook state change causing error "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using useState hook and I have assigned a default value of "single" using the current code:

```
const [mode, setMode] = useState("single")
```

I am trying to make a button that will toggle the state between "single" and "gradient" but I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

This is the inline statement I am trying to use, it makes sense to me but there is an error, is there something I am not seeing?

```
<button onClick={setMode(mode === "single" ? "gradient" : "single")}>
```

Comment: pass in a function, not a function call: `onClick={() => setMode(mode === "single" ? "gradient" : "single")}`. If you pass a function call, the function is called every render

Comment: Ah hah! Got it, makes complete sense, my bad, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS: Maximum update depth exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error)