# Update the state after .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a class component, in which render() function I have a variable, in which I'm mapping my state to create photos out of it and while running this mapping, I want to fill my photoIdsArray with some photo ids - this is working absolutly fine.

```
if(this.state.data)
    {
      photos = (
        <section className="photoGrid">
          {this.state.data.data.results.map((photo,index) => (
            
          <div className="photo" key={photo.id}><img src={photo.urls.regular} alt={photo.alt_description}/>
          <ul className="photoTag">
          {photoIdsArray[index]=photo.id}
          {photo.tags.map((littleTag,index) => ( ...small mapping to create li's))}
          </ul>
          </div>
      ))}
      </section>);
    }
```

The problem is, when Im later trying to get that photoIdsArray into my state, my app is crashing with "Maximum update depth exceeded" and i'm absolutly clueless how to get this working.
I have tried using

```
this.setState({photoIds:array});
```

after that mapping, creating a function, but I'm clueless.
How should I update this properly?

Thats how my state is looking like:

```
state = {
        data:null,
        photoIds:null,
      }
```

Comment: The render function has precisely one job: turn your props and state into HTML. The error you get happens when you also change state inside it, which is a big no-no. Because changing state makes React call render again, and thus state changes again, etc, etc, i.e. infinite loop. There is absolute no need to create your photoId state inside the render method. The proper place to do that is right after `this.state.data` is populated.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell the array you are creating is completely useless; you're just copying the ids of the `results` array.

Comment: @ChrisG About the ids stuff - not really theres a parameter like that in axios response i get from the server, so copying just ids works good. I implemented mapping as you said, where its created, after axios.get and its working like a charm - Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS: Maximum update depth exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error)