# How to fix maximum update depth exceed error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have a component **FetchData** from which I am passing the data to the **ConsumeData** component, But while making a **axios** in **FetchData** I am started to getting an error **maximum update depth exceed error**

**FetchData.js**

```
//Some imports

import axios from axios;

const FetchData = () => {
     const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
     const [userData, setUserData] = useState("");


     useEffect(() => {

      //making an axios call
      axios.get("http://someURl", config)
      .then(userDetailData => {

      //extracting userName
      const userNameExt = userDetailData.user.userName;
     setUserName(userNameExt)

     const userDataFromRes = userDetailData.user.data;
    if(userDetailData.length === 0) {
     console.log("emptyData")
     } else {
        userDataFromRes.map((item) => (
           //Manipulating the userDataFromRes according to need
        ))
       setUserData(userDataFromRes)
     }
    }
    },[])

    return {userName, userData}
}

export default FetchData
```

In the component **ConsumeData** I am using the **userName and userData**

**ConsumeData.js**

```
//Some imports
import FetchData from '../../FetchData';

const ConsumeData = () => {

cosnt {userName, userData} = FetchData();

console.log(userName, userData)

return (
   <div>
   //some code
 </div>
)
}

export default ConsumeData
```

Looking for the solution how I can fix the maximum update depth exceed error.

Comment: check this if it helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error

Comment: This means you are updating some state unconditionally during render which will lead to an infinite re-render loop. The problem may not be in the code shown here. Often this happens when you call a callback instead of passing a reference down as a prop.

Comment: Other than `FetchData` should be named `useFetchData` because it's a custom hook I don't see any overt issues in *this* code snippet. The hook has only a mounting effect so the only way to render loop this hook is to continually remount the component using it. Do you have an error message and stacktrace we can look at?

Comment: @DrewReese full error: 
index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn’t have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.