# Is there a way in React to call a bracket function which changes state, inside other function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call a function `check_empty_cell` which is **declared** as follows:

```
    check_empty_cell(col_index, row_index) {
        var filled_cols = this.find_filled_cols();
        var filled_rows = this.find_filled_rows();
        if (filled_cols.includes(col_index) && filled_rows.includes(row_index)) {

            this.setState({
                empty_cell: false
            })

        }
    }
```

**Function Calling:**

```
    enter_cell(row_index, rows) {
        for (var col_index = 0; col_index < rows; col_index++) {
            this.check_empty_cell(col_index, row_index);
        }
    }
```

So basically, I want to call the `check_empty_cell` function for every pair of `col_index` and `row_index`. But this error comes up:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

This error directs me towards the `setState` used in `check_empty_cell`.

I tried searching for a solution for this, and I found solutions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48497410

According to this solution, I have to use the bracket function since I am sending the parameters. How do I use it and rectify this error?

I tried doing this in

1. **check_empty_cell**:

```
    check_empty_cell(col_index, row_index) {
        var filled_cols = this.find_filled_cols();
        var filled_rows = this.find_filled_rows();
        if (filled_cols.includes(col_index) && filled_rows.includes(row_index)) {
            this.setState({
                empty_cell: false
            })
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

2. **enter_cell**:

```
    enter_cell(row_index, rows, cols) {
        var cells = [];
        console.log('rows: ', rows)
        for (var col_index = 0; col_index < rows; col_index++) {
            if(this.check_empty_cell(col_index, row_index)){
                return cells;
            };
            this.after_empty_cell_push(col_index, row_index, cells, cols);
        }
        return cells
    }
```

But the error still comes up.

Comment: Because the value passed to `setState` is an object, this will always be interpreted as a new value and cause a rerender. So I suspect it is a situation where you are calling `setState`, this triggers a rerender, which causes `enter_cell` to be called again, which causes `setState` to be called again and so on and so on....can you post the entire component?

Comment: The point of the error is that you're calling `setState` too much. Indeed, you'd only need to call that once per render cycle unless something else is setting `empty_cell` to true. So return true from your `check_empty_cell` function if you call `setState` and in `enter_cell`, if `check_empty_cell` returns true, `break` out of the `for` loop.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried that, but the same error appears.

Answer (score 0):

React will indeed limit the number of re-renders within a certain time to a hard limit.  You are calling setState in a loop which will cause a re-render for every iteration of the loop.  You are hitting the limit.  I would suggest calling setState once and break the loop

```js
check_empty_cell(col_index, row_index) {
    var filled_cols = this.find_filled_cols();
    var filled_rows = this.find_filled_rows();
    if (filled_cols.includes(col_index) && filled_rows.includes(row_index)) {

        return false

    }
}

enter_cell(row_index, rows) {
    for (var col_index = 0; col_index < rows; col_index++) {
        if(this.check_empty_cell(col_index, row_index) === false) {
            this.setState({emptyCell: false})
            break;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it fails to compile and throws this error: Unsyntactic break. I can't use break there.

Comment: change to return

Comment: I did try that. I have added the new code to the question.

Comment: stop calling setState in check_empty_cell