# React: Why isn't my component fully rendering unless I type into the input?

Tags: reactjs

The following is my code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {cart.map((p) => {
                i++;
                return <Product key={i} productId={p.productId} />;
             })
            }
        </div>
    )
}


class Product extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                sampleText // this is the part that I refer to
                {products.map((p) => {
                    if (this.props.productId === p.productId) {
                    return <div key={i}>{p.name}</div>; //this is the p.name that I refer to
                    }
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The issue is that the variable p.name is not visible unless I type something into an input or I go to another page and come back to this page. However, "sample text" is visible. My guess is that there isn't enough time for p.name to be rendered, though I'm not too sure. Whenever I tried to force re-rendering, I got [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497358/reactjs-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-error).

Comment: Where are `cart` and `products` declared?

Comment: can you attach the full code? error is somewhere out of the given code

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what was wrong. Basically my allProducts variable was from a firestore database, so it took a while for the allProducts variable to get any data. As a result, when the Product component was reading it, there was nothing and so didn't display anything until it was re-rendered when I entered something in the input.